# Drupal Rules One time login address

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I am trying to send out an email using a drupal onetime login. I have created a custom token which executes the following php.

```
return user_pass_reset_url($user);
```

I then use this in my rule. A link is sent to the user but when they click on the link it says it has all ready been used. I have no idea why because the link in the email looks correct (contains correct user id etc).

Comment: Is this the warning that it's giving?  "You have tried to use a one-time login link which has either been used or is no longer valid. Please request a new one using the form below."

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into using the Login one time module (http://drupal.org/project/login_one_time)? We're using it on a production site and it works great.